# can i select a single and multiple rows by mouse in crystal report preview if not any possibility to select as check box

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5

can I select a single or multiple rows by mouse in crystal report preview. if not any possibility to select as a check box
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ2D7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible via a viewer, hyperlinks, or an on-demand subreport.
But first please explain what is the purpose of the "select".
What is the use case?